# How to install 'Node JS Tools' with dotnet cli

Tags: node.js, .net, msbuild, continuous-integration, gitlab

We are building an ASP.NET Core solution and we recently added a NodeJS project to that solution. Now when we run CI it gives this error:

```
error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v16.0/Node.js Tools/Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v16.0/Node.js Tools/Microsoft.NodejsToolsV2.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

Which makes sense since we are not installing the 'NodeJS Tools' at any point, but we cant find how to install those tools. How do you install the NodeJS Tools with the dotnet cli?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Node.js.redist/)?

Comment: I probably have, but we just ignored the Node project when building and just used the terminal manually as a quick fix and never really looked back. I asked this for a school project we did in the summer, I am not working on it anymore. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dotnet` CLI cannot build these projects as the tools required for these are part of Visual Studio and not the .NET Core distribution or a workload supported by the .NET Sdk.

While you can still use the `dotnet` CLI on .NET Core/Standard csproj files, you cannot use it on solution files containing projects not supported by the CLI.

You can, however, use the `msbuild.exe` from your Visual Studio installation on all projects (suggest using the VS Developer Command Prompt), e.g:

`dotnet build foo.sln` => `msbuild -restore foo.sln`

Comment: The way I understood the question is that even though the NodeJS project can't be built using the .NET Core SDK (of course it can't), the `dotnet CLI` might still be able to install the `NodeJS` runtime, which *then* could be used to build the NodeJS project.

Comment: The NodeJS runtime is something different than the build tools that are part of a visual studio workload. These MSBuild based targets are not part of NodeJS and are not available for the .NET CLI at the moment.

Comment: I am referring to dotnet *CLI*, which can be used as a tool manager and work independently of Visual Studio / msbuild. It'd then only serve as a delegate for other tools / sdks. As an example, you can run `dotnet tool install powershell` and from then on execute Powershell scripts using `dotnet pwsh ./yourscript.ps1`. Doesn't matter if you have .NET code to build or not within your repository, you still get to run Powershell anywhere using this trick. So if NodeJS is available as a custom .NET tool, then it's likely what the OP is looking for.

Comment: the OP wasn't looking for NodeJS itself but the MSBuild targets/tasks part of the Visual Studio workload called "NodeJS Tools". Those would need to be a part of the CLI / SDK distribution itself (see the `sdk/3.1.201` folder in the question) or itself need to be rearchitected as MSBuild SDK which could be installed seperately